# Initialize ArrayList with doubles

Tags: java

I'm trying to initialize an ArrayListto use later in my code, but it seems like it doesn't accept doubles.

`public ArrayList<double> list = new ArrayList<double>();`

It gives an error under 'double', sayin "Syntax error on token "double", Dimensions expected after this token"

Comment: And yet nobody has spotted the `ArraList` typo...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An `ArrayList` doesn't take raw data types (ie, `double`). Use the wrapper class (ie, `Double`) instead :

```
public ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, as of Java 7, no need to specify that it's for the `Double` class, it will figure it out automatically, so you can just specify `<>` for the ArrayList.

Comment: Nice use of the diamond operator, it makes code look so much neater.

Comment: I think, it should be `List<Double>list=...`

Comment: @ginz It can be, but doesn't have to be. Since OP used `ArrayList`, so did I. Advantage of using `List` instead is for genericity of programming, but it's not 100% necessary.

Comment: It is, that's why I've just commented this instead of editing. I think, that may be useful for novices in Java, that will look inside such a questions. Just the educational issue.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `Wrapper class` for `double` which is `Double`. Try

```
public ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java, ArrayLists (and other generic classes) only accept object references as types, not primitive data types. There are wrapper classes that allow you to emulate using primitives, though: `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short`, `Character`, `Integer`, `Long`, `Float` and `Double`;

```
public ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
//or "public ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<>();" in Java 1.7 and beyond
```

Values inside are "autoboxed" and "autounboxed" so you can treat `doubles` as `Doubles` without problems, and vice versa. You may need to explicitly specify whether you want arguments to be treated as `int` or `Integer` when dealing with lists of integral types, though, to disambiguate between cases like `remove(int index)` and `remove(Object o)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
public ArrayList<Double> doubleList = new ArrayList<>();
```

From Java `1.7`, you don't need to write Double while `initializing ArrayList`, so it's your choice to write Double in `new ArrayList<>(); or new ArrayList<Double>();` or not.. otherwise it's not compulsory.

Also known as a `dynamic array`.

No need to pre-determine the number of elements up 
front, just add to the array as we need it